# How to transpose grouped columns to rows with key

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm hoping to transpose groups of data in columns to rows, while maintaining a unique key.

Here's what I mean:

[Current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRiPr.png) (CSV below)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGKH3.png)

In case it helps, there are up to (but not necessarily) 25 `tags` per `filename`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

CSV of current data:

```
filename,tag1,confidence1,tag2,confidence2,tag3,confidence3
filename1,water,0.760709643,green,0.733112454,nature,0.721782982
filename2,interior,0.787028313,room,0.752214372,architecture,0.72691071
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

- Start at `Data => Get&Transform => from Text/CSV`
- After selecting your file, select `Transform` on the window that opens.
- Go to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the correct file name on line 3

  - Replace the existing code with the M-code below
  - Replace the file name in line 3 with your own file name
- Examine each step in the `Applied Steps` window and the comments to see how this works.

**M Code**

```
let
    //read in the CSV file
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\NewFile.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    
    //unpivot to reduce to three columns -- filename, attribute and Value
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"filename"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

    //Split off the number from the end of each tag/column
    //That number, in a column by itself, builds a relationship with the filename
  
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", 
            "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    //Group by Filename
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Character Transition", {"filename"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [filename=nullable text, Attribute.1=nullable text, Value=any, #"Integer-Division"=number]}}),
    
    //Pivot each grouped table
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Pivot([Grouped],
                        List.Distinct(Table.Column([Grouped],"Attribute.1")),
                        "Attribute.1", "Value")),

    //Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"filename", "Grouped"}),

    //Expand the table, then set the correct data types
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", {"filename", "tag", "confidence"}, {"filename", "tag", "confidence"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"filename", type text}, {"tag", type text}, {"confidence", type number}})

in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]